# I need to append a list into another list (specific issue)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split, append

This is my code:

```
files = open('clean.txt').readlines()
print files
finallist = []
for items in files:
  new = items.split()
  new.append(finallist)
```

And since the file of text is too huge, here is an example of "print files":

```
files = ['chemistry leads outstanding another story \n', 'rhapsodic moments blow narrative prevent bohemian rhapsody']
```

I really need each line separated by '\n' to be splitted in words & placed in a list of list just like the format below:

```
outcome = [['chemistry','leads','outstanding', 'another', 'story'],['rhapsodic','moments','blow', 'narrative', 'prevent', 'bohemian', 'rhapsody']]
```

I've tried methods just like the first code given and it returns an empty list. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `finallist.append(new)`? Maybe a minimum of proof reading would be good before posting...

Comment: hey @Julien , sorry it wasn't proof reading. I really did that mistake. Silly mistake. Thanks alot! I'm closing this.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of your code is backwards, it seems.  Instead of

```
new.append(finallist)
```

it should be

```
finallist.append(new)
```

I changed the last line to the version above, and the result was a list (finallist) containing 2 sub-lists.  Here is the code that seems to work:

```
files = open('clean.txt').readlines()
print files
finallist = []
for items in files:
  new = items.split()
  finallist.append(new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to reduce line

```
finallist = [i.split() for i in files]
```